question about $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ i.e. the complex bounded sequences.
Considering $l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ (Banach space) and let $T:l^\infty(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded functional. For $\psi \in l^\infty(\mathbb{N})$ define $(\psi T):l^\infty(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by $\phi \mapsto T(\psi \cdot \phi)$.
Let $\psi_i:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a finite amount of characteristic functions such that $\sum \psi_i = 1$. I am trying to show that $$\|T\|=\sum\|\psi_iT\|.$$
(It is an exercise in the textbook I am reading right now, by Hörmander.)
I know that $T(f) = T( \sum \psi_i f) = \sum T(\psi_i f) = \sum (\psi_i T)(f)$. Hence, $\|T\|\le\sum\|\psi_iT\|$. But am having trouble showing the reverse.

Why do you think the result is true?

@Conrad: OP's (now self-deleted) comment answering your question is now included in the post.

For each $i$, $\psi_iT$ is a bounded linear functional as $\vert T(\psi_i \cdot \phi)\vert\leq\Vert T\Vert\Vert\psi_i\Vert\Vert\phi\Vert=\Vert T\Vert\Vert\phi\Vert$, or $\Vert\psi_iT\Vert\leq\Vert T\Vert$.
By definition of operator norm there exists $f_i$ satisfying $\Vert f_i\Vert=1$ and $\Vert \psi_iT\Vert-\epsilon/2^i \leq \vert (\psi_iT)(f_i)\vert \leq \Vert \psi_iT\Vert$ for any fixed $\epsilon\gt 0$. We can assume further that $f_i$ has $0$ on those components where $\psi_i$ has $0$. By replacing $f_i$ by $\left(sgn[\psi_i T(f_i)]^{-1}f_i\right)$, where $sgn(z)=z/|z|$ for $z\neq0$, we can assume that $(\psi_i T)(f_i)$ are positive reals.
Now let $f=\sum f_i$, then $f=\sum\psi_i f_i$, $\Vert f\Vert=1$,
$$\Vert T\Vert
\geq\vert T(f)\vert
=\vert T(\sum\psi_if_i)\vert
=\vert\sum(\psi_iT)(f_i)\vert
=\sum\vert(\psi_iT)(f_i)\vert\\
\geq\sum\left(\Vert\psi_iT\Vert-\epsilon/2^i\right)
\geq\sum\Vert\psi_iT\Vert-\epsilon.$$
The reverse inequality then holds since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.

+1 but your function "sgn" should be defined appropriately since you are applying it to complex numbers. You should also specify that the indices $i$ are assumed to be non-negative integers.

thanks, this makes sense. I could be mistaken, but should we just have instead of $\epsilon/2^i$ we should have $\epsilon$ divided by the fixed amount of characteristic functions such that $\sum \psi_i = 1$?

It’s just my habit to use $\sum\epsilon /2^i$ as it will $\leq\epsilon$ even when there are countably many indices. In this question it makes no difference, except that $\sum\epsilon /2^i$ won’t exactly equal $\epsilon$.

Define projection maps $\pi_i:l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$ as $\pi_i(\{a_k\}):= \{(\psi_i)_ka_k\}$ [pointwise multiplication].
$\psi_i$ make a partition of unity, so $\sum{\pi_i}=Id$ on $l^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$. [Check pointwise]
Observe that $\psi_iT = \pi_i^{*}T$, and by dualizing the last equation, the claim follows.

Why $|\sum\pi_i^(T)|=\sum|\pi_i^(T)|$?
